# Como posso criar um filtro para preencher com zero a esquerda no angular?

Tags: angularjs

Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação utilizando `Laravel` e `AngularJS`. Eu sempre achei trabalhoso formatar um número para preencher com zeros em Javascript, por isso eu optei por usar o Laravel para me trazer o número do campo `id` já formatado com o preenchimento do zero.

Porém agora eu gostaria de fazer pelo AngularJS, já que eu percebi que os componentes dele (ou mesmo os que são criados) podem ser altamente reutilizados.

Qual é o passo para eu criar uma função para formatar os valores exibidos na `view` preenchendo zeros à esquerda no Angular?

Já existe alguma função para isso ou eu preciso criar uma? Como proceder?

Por exemplo:

```
 <tr ng-repeat="u in usuarios">
      <td ng-bind="usuario.id|preencher_com_quatro_zeros_a_esquerda"></td>
      <td ng-bind="usuario.nome"></td>

 </tr>
```

No exemplo preciso que `preencher_com_quatro_zeros_a_esquerda` me retorne um número formatado com 4 zeros a esquerda. Como fazer?

Comment: A pessoa que negativou poderia fazer a gentileza de explicar o que há de errado com a pergunta?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Alternativa:

```
filter('numberFixedLen', function () {
    return function (n, len) {
        var num = parseInt(n, 10);
        len = parseInt(len, 10);
        return (isNaN(num) || isNaN(len)) ? n : ( 1e10 + "" + num ).slice(-len);
    };
});
```

- 1e10 significa 10000000000, que é "somado" como string no número original, e depois "cortado" pelo slice.
- para números com mais de 10 dígitos, precisa ser adaptado o 1e10

Fonte: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21712550/916193

Possível melhoria: trocar o `1e10` por `Math.pow( 10, len )`

Foi adaptado e melhorado com mais dígitos e verificação.

<sub>Edit conforme comentário:</sub>

Como é uma função normalmente usada para casas fixas, ela vai cortar números com mais de 10 dígitos. Se não é o comportamento desejado, precisa de um ajuste. Segue exemplo de alteração:

```
return (isNaN(num) || isNaN(len) || (""+num).length>len) ? n : (1e10 + "" + num).slice(-len);
// Acrescente isso               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Comment: Boa, nem precisou de `while` (apesar de não ser um problema, prefiro sem).

Comment: O único problema é que se o número tiver maior quantidade de dígitos, está sendo cortado!

Answer (score 7):

Implementação como Filter:

```
.filter('numberFixedLen', function () {
    return function (n, len) {
        var num = parseInt(n, 10);
        len = parseInt(len, 10);
        if (isNaN(num) || isNaN(len)) {
            return n;
        }
        num = ''+num;
        while (num.length < len) {
            num = '0'+num;
        }
        return num;
    };
});
```

Uso:

```
{{meuValor | numberFixedLen:4}}
```

[Fonte](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17648014/how-can-i-use-an-angularjs-filter-to-format-a-number-to-have-leading-zeros/17648547#17648547).

Answer (score 4):

Outra opção

```
.filter('numberFixedLen' function () {
    return function (a, b) {
        return (1e4 + a + "").slice(-b)
    }
});
```

Uso:

```
{{ valor | numberFixedLen:4 }}
```

Comment: Resposta em inglês: http://stackoverflow.com/a/21712550/3096922